# Не принимает заданные значения логина и пароля

Tags: java, android

Не могу разобраться. При вводе заданных значений логина и пароля не происходит переход на следующее активити. Пишет "Try again" как при вводе неправильных значений.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText login_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login = login_view.getText().toString();
    EditText pass_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    password = pass_view.getText().toString();

    myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (login.equals("hey") && password.equals("nigga")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Oh, it's you again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),Menu.class);
                intent.putExtra("login",login);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: странно, вам надо чтобы логин был hey а пароль nigga?

Comment: @СергейГрушин да

Comment: не заметил сразу)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши переменные `login` и `password` инициализируются введенными данными прямо в методе `onCreate()`, тоесть при старте приложения в них забиваются пустые кавычки и они не соответствуют вашим заданным значениям. Надо так

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final EditText login_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
final EditText pass_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (login_view.getText().toString().equals("hey") && pass_view.getText().toString().equals("nigga")) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Oh, it's you again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),Menu.class);
            intent.putExtra("login",login);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}
});}
```

Тоесть логин и пароль проверяются при клике на кнопку, а не при запуске активности